# Image URLs stopped working due to Permalinks?

Tags: images, filesystem

I've been changing my Permalinks and changing my site the the "www" version (Which I think has broken my image and video links). All my images are "red x" now, both inside the library and the posts themselves. I have been looking in my cpanel and all the file paths are correct, but if I try to view them through WP or even just copy the url and try it within my browser, it appears broken.

Is there a way to fix this at all? Other than reload everything back up. :-(

To update: I just re-uploaded an image and it was saved as header1.png, so WP can see that there is another image in there. It's strange because all the paths seem to match in my library to where they are stored within cpanel.

I feel that because I cahnged the permalink structure to %category%/%postname% that that is affecting the image structure which is wp-content/uploads/%year%/%month%/%imagename% by the looks of it.

Comment: do you have this live anywhere? i don't believe the permalink structure effects the uploaded image URLs

Comment: No it was locally. I think the problem was due to me changing to the www structure. I noticed on one page that an image had a padlock on it. So i reverted it all back to the non-www - it was too much hassle. I deleted and reset all my .htaccess files a few times and flushed my w3 caches to try and get it to work prior to changing back. Nothing worked. Appreciate the help though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you've monkeyed with your www structure you can change the image URLs (since they are hard-coded in the img src) using the following plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and could only fixed as:

- Copy the problem image to same directory.
- Delete the original
- Rename the copied file to original name.

Let's say it is named as "xyz.jpg", then once you copy it, you will have "xyz - copy.jpg"

Remove the "xyz.jpg" and rename the "xyz-copy.jpg" to "xyz.jpg"

I am pretty sure it is not the best solution. But it worked for me.